# Maven, how to run test-compile together with compile

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a code that use Annotation Processor, when I compile the classes is fine to classes from `src/main/java`, but the test (`src/test/java`) classes is not compiled, this way I can not run my unit test naturally, to do that I have to run manually the `mvn test-compile` command.

**How I can configure pom.xml file to run `test-compile` using `maven-compiler-plugin` together with `compile` command?**

This is my build:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <compilerArgs>
              <arg>-parameters</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
              <path>
                <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
              </path>
              <path>
                <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
              </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>test-compile</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                  <arg>-parameters</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                  <path>
                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                    <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                  </path>
                  <path>
                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                    <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                  </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
```

using `apache-maven-3.6.2` + `Eclipse 2019-09`.

Comment: Does my answer below answer your question?

Comment: unfortunately no, the **Annotation Processor** doesn't run correctly in eclipse IDE, I'm trying to do a workaround with `maven-compiler-plugin`+`Eclipse`, not maven alone, command line works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It is not completely clear to me what you want.

Maven has a lifecycle. If you call a specific phase (like `test-compile`), all previous phases are also called automatically.

So if you want to compile both your classes and your test classes, you just call `mvn test-compile`. If you want to compile your classes and your test classes and run the tests, call `mvn test`.

Comment: If I run `mvn test-compile` the Annotation Processor works generating the classes that will be injected. But using `Build all` from eclipse the unit test classes is generated and the **Annotation Processor** not generate the classes. I think this is a Eclipse Bug for annotation processor, so I am trying to resolve by pom.xml with another way to force eclipse run annotation processor correctly.

Comment: What is "Build all"? This does not sound like a Maven command. To build the whole project, call `clean verify` or `clean install`. Do this through "Run As" -> "Maven build...".

Comment: Thanks, this worked, configuring a maven command into Eclipse. I was looking for a `Ctrl+B` in Eclipse. But it's ok by `Run As`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would just run the command: mvn clean install

Comment: I am looking for a way to run with `Eclipse` + `maven-compiler-plugin`, just maven works.

Comment: To build a Maven project from Eclipse, you use "Run As" -> "Maven build..." and then enter e.g. `clean install`. You do not call any other Eclipse mechanism explicitly.